# Present Scene from a helper class

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, sprite-kit, storekit

I am developing a game for iOS that has in game currency. I have an SKSceneStore that has an SKLabelNode that displays the player's in-game-wealth. This label's value is initialized when the user navigates to SKSceneStore (from a saved NSUserDefaults value).

For the user to purchase more in-game currency, I have a helper class, IAPHelper (from Ray Wenderlich's tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial and http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation) and one of its methods is "provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier". This is the method that is called after a successful transaction, and I add XXX in-game currency to the player's in-game wealth.

My problem is I am not sure how to 'refresh' the SKLabelNode with the user's in-game wealth (in the SKSceneStore). How can I do this? One crude solution I came up with is that I could just reload the entire SKSceneStore with the following code:

```
SKSceneStore *reinitializeStore = [SKSceneStore alloc]init];
SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.5];
[reinitializeStore.view presentScene:reinitializeStore transition:reveal];
```

However, this code doesn't work.

Comment: Is the refresh dependent on an event that happens in the class displaying the label or from an event in another class?

Comment: refresh depends on an event in another class (not the class displaying the label).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a more elegant solution and used the following code:

in "provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier"

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reinitializeStore" object:self];
```

and then in my SKSceneStore I used

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(powerUpHUD) name:@"reinitializeStore" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just remove the label from the scene, create a new label with the updated wealth, and add it back to the scene?

Comment: My problem is that I'm waiting for the response to an event that happens in a separate class from the one displaying the label. I don't know what code to use to use to do what you've described from the separate class.